# split data into month in postgres

Tags: database, postgresql

i have a table like bellow in postgres

| start_at | end_at |
| --- | --- |
| 17/1/2023 | 15/3/2023 |

i want to split this like bellow

| start_at | end_at |
| --- | --- |
| 17/1/2023 | 31/1/2023 |
| 01/2/2023 | 28/2/2023 |
| 1/3/2023 | 15/3/2023 |

I have tried generate series of postgres but not able to generate desire row. Please someone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Recommended Solution(h/t: *[Prosenjit Chongder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19663148/prosenjit-chongder)*):

The solution using ***[`generate_series`](https://www.sqliz.com/postgresql-ref/generate_series/)*** function is much more compact.

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(GREATEST(y, c.start_at), 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS start_at,
       TO_CHAR(LEAST(y + INTERVAL '1 month' - INTERVAL '1 day', c.end_at), 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS end_at
FROM date_ranges c, 
     generate_series(date_trunc('month', c.start_at::timestamp), date_trunc('month', c.end_at::timestamp), INTERVAL '1 month') y
ORDER BY GREATEST(y, c.start_at), LEAST(y + INTERVAL '1 month' - INTERVAL '1 day', c.end_at);
```

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g4EQFkE3psu8C282uwv8r5/0)

---

#### Older Solution:

You will need a recursive [Common table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) to acheive your purpose.

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE date_split(start_at, end_at, current_start, current_end) AS (
  SELECT start_at, end_at,
         start_at, LEAST(end_at, (date_trunc('MONTH', start_at) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH' - INTERVAL '1 day')::DATE)
  FROM date_ranges
  WHERE start_at <= end_at
  UNION ALL
  SELECT start_at, end_at,
         (current_end + INTERVAL '1 day')::DATE,
         LEAST(end_at, (date_trunc('MONTH', current_end + INTERVAL '1 day') + INTERVAL '1 MONTH' - INTERVAL '1 day')::DATE)
  FROM date_split
  WHERE current_end < end_at
)
SELECT TO_CHAR(current_start, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS start_at, TO_CHAR(current_end, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS end_at
FROM date_split
ORDER BY current_start;
```

outputs:

```
start_at    end_at
17/01/2023  31/01/2023
01/02/2023  28/02/2023
01/03/2023  15/03/2023
```

[DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/82ZvPsSZnDmM2Dhtj93cfq/1)

Comment: with out union i have achieved same result by 

SELECT c.name, extract('year' FROM y)::int AS year, 
 extract('month' FROM y)::int AS month,
 GREATEST(y, c.start_at) AS start_day,
 LEAST(y + interval '1 month - 1 day', c.end_at) AS end_day, total_campaign_cost, duration
 FROM campaigns c, 
 generate_series(date_trunc('month', c.start_at::timestamp), 
     date_trunc('month', c.end_at::timestamp), 
     interval '1 month') y)

i thing it is more compact

Comment: @ProsenjitChongder, note that my answer using `generate_series` (which was posted prior to mandy8055 revising this answer), does not repeat expressions. In general, redundant code should be avoided. To modify my solution to use a different span (e.g., weeks or quarters) only requires changing the calculation for `end_at` and the series generation parameters (`month_start` should also be renamed, perhaps to something like `period_start` to make it interval agnostic).

Answer (score 1):

The following will generate the described results:

```
WITH parms AS (SELECT '2023-01-17'::date AS start_at, '2023-03-15'::date AS end_at)
SELECT greatest(parms.start_at, g.month_start)::date AS start_at,
       least(parms.end_at, g.month_start + interval '1' MONTH - interval '1' DAY)::date AS end_at
FROM parms
CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series(date_trunc('month',parms.start_at), parms.end_at, interval '1' MONTH) g(month_start)
ORDER BY start_at;
```

Results:

| start_at | end_at |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-17 | 2023-01-31 |
| 2023-02-01 | 2023-02-28 |
| 2023-03-01 | 2023-03-15 |